# lilypond redefining guitar chord spelling for each bookpart

Tags: guitar, chords, lilypond

I have 30 or so songs that were individually created that I now want to typeset as bookparts into a single book. Of course other than pagination I want each part to look the same as when it is typeset separately.
However I'm seeing that if a chord spelling is defined one way in one song/part and a different way in a subsequent song/part, then the last definition gets applied to the whole book. I'll illustrate with a simple example below:

part1.ly

```
pieceTitle = "part 1. example 1"

\include "predefined-guitar-fretboards.ly"

\storePredefinedDiagram #default-fret-table
                        \chordmode { c'' }
                        #guitar-tuning
                        "x;x;10-3;9-2;8-1;8-1;"

chordnames = \chordmode { c''1 }
symbols = \relative { \key c \major \time 4/4 <c' e g c>1 \bar "|." }

scorePart = {
  <<
  \new ChordNames { \chordnames }
  \new FretBoards { \chordnames }
  \new Staff { \clef "treble_8" \symbols }
  >>
}
```

This produces
[image]

part2.ly

```
pieceTitle = "part 2. example 2"

\include "predefined-guitar-fretboards.ly"

\storePredefinedDiagram #default-fret-table
                        \chordmode { c'' }
                        #guitar-tuning
                        "x;3-1-(;5-3-(;5-3;5-3-);3-1-);"

chordnames = \chordmode { c''1 }
symbols = \relative { \key c \major \time 4/4 <c g' c e g>1 \bar "|." }

scorePart = {
  <<
  \new ChordNames { \chordnames }
  \new FretBoards { \chordnames }
  \new Staff { \clef "treble_8" \symbols }
  >>
}
```

this produces
[image]

However when I put these 2 parts together into a book, the part2 definition of the chord prevails and gets applied to both parts.

book.ly:

```
\include "./part1.ly"
\bookpart {
  \header { title = \pieceTitle }
  \score { \scorePart }
}

\include "./part2.ly"
\bookpart {
  \header { title = \pieceTitle }
  \score { \scorePart }
}
```

produces:
[image]

I know that I can name the chords differently, e.g., use c''' in part2. But I have 30+ songs that were created separately. I shouldn't have to coordinate all the parts (a logistical nightmare) just because I want to include them together in a single book. Also some of the more common chords end up having like 10 different spellings across the whole collection.

There must be another way.

Please advise.

BTW I'm using 2.24.3

Comment: If you don't need multiple songs on a page you can print each song to PDF and just combine them.

Comment: Yes. I am doing that for now as a workaround. But it screws up pagination, and ruins any chance of a reasonable table of contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing

```
\storePredefinedDiagram #default-fret-table
                        \chordmode { c'' }
                        #guitar-tuning
                        "x;x;10-3;9-2;8-1;8-1;"
```

you modify the hash table `default-fret-table` which (by default) provides the context value for `predefinedDiagramTable`. This will thus modify the value in all places. This happens in the parsing step. Lilypond works in multiple steps:

1. File is parsed. This will register scores and such
2. Registered scores are iterated and by the use of engravers translated into a set of graphical objects (grobs)
3. Grobs are spaced and formatted
4. Result is printed by output backend

Now, fretboard symbols are only determined either by the engraver or by a grob callback (too lazy to look it up), so this happens only after everything is parsed. Thus your second diagram simply overwrites the first one before they even are used.

What you need to do instead is that instead of mutating the default you should create your own table, like this:

```
\include "predefined-guitar-fretboards.ly"

#(define fret-table-A (alist->hash-table (hash-table->alist default-fret-table)))
#(define fret-table-B (alist->hash-table (hash-table->alist default-fret-table)))

\storePredefinedDiagram #fret-table-A
                        \chordmode { c'' }
                        #guitar-tuning
                        "x;x;10-3;9-2;8-1;8-1;"

\storePredefinedDiagram #fret-table-B
                        \chordmode { c'' }
                        #guitar-tuning
                        "x;3-1-(;5-3-(;5-3;5-3-);3-1-);"

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

pieceTitle = "part 1. example 1"

chordnames = \chordmode { c''1 }
symbols = \relative { \key c \major \time 4/4 <c' e g c>1 \bar "|." }

scorePart = {
  <<
  \new ChordNames { \chordnames }
  \new FretBoards \with {
    predefinedDiagramTable = #fret-table-A
  } { \chordnames }
  \new Staff { \clef "treble_8" \symbols }
  >>
}

\bookpart {
  \header { title = \pieceTitle }
  \score { \scorePart }
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

pieceTitle = "part 2. example 2"

chordnames = \chordmode { c''1 }
symbols = \relative { \key c \major \time 4/4 <c g' c e g>1 \bar "|." }

scorePart = {
  <<
  \new ChordNames { \chordnames }
  \new FretBoards \with {
    predefinedDiagramTable = #fret-table-B
  } { \chordnames }
  \new Staff { \clef "treble_8" \symbols }
  >>
}

\bookpart {
  \header { title = \pieceTitle }
  \score { \scorePart }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much. Worked like a charm. Can you link to the documentation where I would have found this? I'm still trying to get more familiar with the documentation itself.

Comment: @CharlieMa https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/snippets/fretted-strings.html#fretted-strings-fretboards-alternate-tables